# rviz segfault in fuerte

Tags: rviz, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I just started using ROS and had a problem with rviz.

```
rosrun rviz rviz 
[ INFO] [1337948693.539857743]: rviz revision number 1.8.11
[ INFO] [1337948693.540013978]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried different OGRE modes:

```
export OGRE_RTT_MODE=Copy
export OGRE_RTT_MODE=FBO
```

Neither of them worked.
I finally get into the bin directory of rviz and debug the exectuable. Here is the result (for the entire output, please see [here](http://pastebin.com/2aggeYet)):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x019df739 in QMetaObject::indexOfSignal (this=0x1ad3d34, signal=0x27db89 "changed()") at /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.5.3/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp:587
587     /var/tmp/qt-x11-src-4.5.3/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

And for those who are willing to help me - they say in a bug report ([here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4830#comment:16)) that there is a script called system_info.sh - I attach the system info [here](http://pastebin.com/aQ1mgLDd).

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34837/rviz-segfault-in-fuerte/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2012-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dipsgautam](https://answers.ros.org/users/24624/dipsgautam/) on 2015-10-19**:
Hi,
I have exactly the same error except the rviz revision number is 1.8.17.
Have you figured out the root cause of the issue?
Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
@dipsgautam: this is a very old question (Fuerte is over 5 ROS versions old), so I advise you to post a new question. Do link to this one in your new one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please read the page http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#Segfault_during_startup

and try each mode of these: copy PBuffer FBO, maybe one of them will work!

---

Originally posted by [Barton.Qi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3040/barton.qi/) with karma: 41 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0